# Cloud storage systems

Tags: php, cloud

I am currently using the Rackspace Cloud for cloud storage of files (pictures, videos, documents etc). I use the PHP API to access the Cloud (rather than through a public URL as I need the files to be private) but the latency on it is pretty bad. It takes about 4.5 seconds to connect.

Can anyone recommend a better and faster option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) is reasonably priced and has always been speedy in our daily use. Their ACL permissions will let you have private files easily.

We're currently using [this](http://undesigned.org.za/2007/10/22/amazon-s3-php-class) PHP client for it.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Google storage](http://code.google.com/apis/storage/)

they give 5GB for free (100 GB if you are signed up before May 10th, 2011)

Answer (score 0):

We're using the SMEStorage API and client tools from their Google Code site - they have some nice features in their API and some good code samples. You should also try and get hold of their free cloud Dashboard which supports Cloud Files